# Variable with Array of objects in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, dbeaver

I'm trying to write sql which will create table and Index on specified columns.
so i need something like 2 dimentional array with value like below -

```
-- tablename , keys (array of strings )

table_details:= {table1, 'column1, column2'}, {table2, 'column3'}

for each tabledetail from table_details

-- Create table 1st value from tabledetail 

   For each 2nd value from tabledetail  
       -- Create Index for all columns specified
   loop end 
loop end
```

Comment: Probably better to use JSON as `select '{"table_name": "table1" , "col_names": ["column1", "column2"]}'::jsonb` then `select '{"table_name": "table1" , "col_names": ["column1", "column2"]}'::jsonb ->> 'table_name'; table1` and `select jsonb_array_elements('{"table_name": "table1" , "col_names": ["column1", "column2"]}'::jsonb -> 'col_names');` to get column names.

Comment: If you want to use Postgres array it would need to be: `'{{table1, "column1, column2"}, {table2, "column3"}}'::varchar[]`.

Comment: Need Table with related columns  mapping in some variable, trying 2nd option

Comment: create custom array type to support object element